# Music temperaments

Tags: temperament

Why so much different temperaments (in use?)?
My question isn't about the A initial 440, 442, 415 or other value in hertz. If we take A 440Hz it mean that this A must to stay all the time 440Hz, right? Our memory (depending of our education) have only one right place(frequency) for each note! Using different temperament is not logic in this case. Sure that we can tolerate little deviations but I think inacceptable to have different places for the same note in different tonality when inequal temperament is used! Why nobody try to find a new equal temperament with 12 half tones? In the standard ET today the K for the half tone is 1.059463...(when a just octave is used) but till K 1.059643...(with pure fifth) how many ET's we have to explore?! I ask me if it exists a software for simulate different ET using different K? There we have 178  K possibles to try how it sounds! Any ideas?

Comment: If you take the octave as your basis and divide it into 12 equal tones then the ratio can only be 1.059463 (the twelfth root of 2). If you take a different number you either don't get exact octaves, or you get more tones per octave.

Comment: "Our memory (depending of our education) have only one right place(frequency) for each note! " what makes you think that? Most of us have relative ears that can't tell the difference except when played within a reasonable amount of time

Comment: They're not necessarily all in equal use. There may be experimentalists today who "explore" all possibilities for no reason other than to do so, but *historically*, a handful of temperaments got most of the use.

Comment: It sounds like you feel there are too many temperaments, but then suggest... yet another one?!?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis https://xkcd.com/927/?